# SQL Query between multiple databases needing some correlations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have another problem with the elaboration of a MySQL query.

I have two databases and each one of them has a database containing cities.
My client got his old website from another company and I need to get the correlation between the old database cities and the new ones.

Here's the structure of the databases:

Database1

```
CREATE TABLE new_cities (
 new_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 new_postal_code INT,
 new_city_name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Database2

```
CREATE TABLE old_cities (
 old_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 old_postal_code INT,
 old_city_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE old_entries (
entry_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
city_id INT
);
```

So I have to transfer the entries from a database to the other but the problem is that the old_entries.old_city_id will not correspond to the right cities from the new database because the ids are differents.

I want to get my old_entries.* plus a field (or replacing directly the old_city_id) containing the new_city_id that I would have got by the zipcode correspondance.

Here's my current query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT database1.new_cities.id FROM database1.new_cities, database2.old_entries WHERE  database1.new_cities.zipcode = 
(SELECT database2.old_cities.cp FROM database2.old_cities, database2.old_entries WHERE database2.old_entries.city_id = database2.old_cities.old_id)
) AS newcp FROM database2.old_entries WHERE 1
```

I get the logical message that my subquery returns more than one row.

The structure should be something around:

1 - Take my old_entry

2 - Take the old_entry.city_id and get the corresponding zipcode from the old_cities table

3 - Take this zipcode and get the new_cities.new_id corresponding to this zipcode

4 - Add this new_id to the row AS newcp (or directly replace the city_id's value with it)

How can I make the query get the corresponding new_city_id AS newcp for each row ?

EDIT: Samples

Entry sample:

```
ID| CITY_ID
1 | 23000
```

old_cities sample

```
ID    | ZIPCODE | NAME
23000 |  75000  | Paris
```

new_cities sample

```
ID    | ZIPCODE | NAME
23000 |  13000  | Marseille
23500 |  75000  | Paris
```

Expected result:

```
ID  |  OLD_CITY_ID  | NEW_CITY_ID
 1  |     23000     |   23500
```

or eventually

```
ID |  CITY_ID
 1 |   23500
```

So we can see that if my transfered entry keep its city_id, it won't be corresponding to Paris anymore but to Marseille, so I need to replace the 23000 in entry.city_id by 23500, which is the new id of the city Paris, identified by its zipcode (75000)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results?  I find your explanation a bit hard to follow.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Could you add an example of what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query to get corresponding new city IDs would be the following:

```
SELECT database2.old_entries.entry_id AS id, database1.new_cities.new_id AS city_id
FROM database2.old_entries AS entries 
    JOIN database2.old_cities AS old_cities ON (entries.city_id = old_cities.old_id)
    JOIN database1.new_cities AS new_cities ON (old_cities.old_postal_code = new_cities.new_postal_code)
```

This would return all entry IDs with matching new city IDs. See also how [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) works.

If you want to insert the result to a table, you can then use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO new_entries (entry_id, city_id)
SELECT database2.old_entries.entry_id AS id, database1.new_cities.new_id AS city_id
FROM database2.old_entries AS entries 
    JOIN database2.old_cities AS old_cities ON (entries.city_id = old_cities.old_id)
    JOIN database1.new_cities AS new_cities ON (old_cities.old_postal_code = new_cities.new_postal_code)
```

Comment: Damn, that was simple ... Thanks a lot for the answer, that works now !